# How do I update 1 DE based on data in 2nd DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, activity

I'm fairly new with SQL. I have 2 data extensions. DE1 is a list of email addresses and changes each day. DE2 is for counting how many times each address appears in DE1.

So, my question is, how would I create a SQL query that follows this logic:

- For each email address in DE1
- If exists in DE2, count = count + 1
- If doesn't exist in DE2, create new row adding email address and count = 1

I hope this makes sense. I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT a.emailaddres,
CASE WHEN b.emailaddress IS NOT NULL THEN b.Count + 1 ELSE 1 END as Count
FROM [DE1] a
FULL OUTER JOIN [DE2] b
ON a.emailaddress = b.emailaddress
```

should do it for you. Might need to tweak it a bit as I had to do it off the cuff.

This requires:

1. DE1 to have field emailaddress
2. DE2 to have a Count field and an emailaddress field to match against.

Comment: This is a great start, thank you.  I was able to get the query working using your code as a guide, and it's really close. If the email address already exists in DE2, it correctly adds +1 to the count column, but if the email address does not exist, it does nothing. I need it to add a new row when the email address doesn't exist in DE2.

Comment: sorry misunderstood. My update to `FULL OUTER JOIN` should solve that issue.

Comment: It turns out it almost works. When DE2 is empty and I run the SQL query, it correctly adds all of the new email addresses from DE1 to DE2 and properly puts a 1 in the counting column. BUT, if there are already existing rows in DE2, it does not add new rows. It only updates the matching email address rows by correctly adding +1.

So, my problem is it only adds new rows when DE2 is completely empty. I have the data action set to Update, because that seems like the correct choice, but I have tried all 3.

Comment: What is the target DE and Data Action? Are you targeting DE2?

Comment: Data Action is Update, and yes. I am targeting DE2.

Comment: well then according to their docs, this should be 100% correct. There is no reason it should not be adding new records in as well as updating. Might be worth a support case ticket.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Gortonington. I really appreciate it. I happened to notice last night that every entry in the Action Log has "Automation failed due to system error."  I plan to explore other ways to accomplish my objective. :)
ACTION: Error, SOURCE: Run Once, DURATION: Less than 1s, DETAIL: _Automation failed due to system error._

Comment: I would check the following - 1.) verify that the target DE you set still exists. 2.) verify that the name/key of the target DE has not been changed after Query was created. 3.) Try recreating the query exactly, but as a different name and see if it still shows that error.  I have had unexplained system errors before that and when recreated work perfectly.  SFMC support may be able to provide further insight into the error if none of the above work.